# Is there a natural measurable structure on the $\sigma$-algebra of a measurable space?

Tags: measure-theory, pr.probability, gn.general-topology, order-theory, ct.category-theory

Let $(X, \Sigma)$ denote a measurable space. Is there a non-trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma^1$ of subsets of $\Sigma$ so that $(\Sigma, \Sigma^1)$ is also a measurable space?

---

Here is one natural candidate. I'm not certain, but based on answers to related questions, I think this might be the Effros Borel structure that Gerald Edgar has mentioned [**here**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1388/is-there-a-natural-measures-on-the-space-of-measurable-functions/1427#1427) and [**here**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104305/nice-sigma-algebra-on-set-of-measurable-functions/104315#104315).

The $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ is an ordered set under the canonical relation given by subset inclusion $\subseteq$, and is therefore naturally equipped with a specialization topology. The closed sets are generated by downward-closed sets, and the closure of a singleton is its down-set:$$\overline{\{A\}} = \{ B \in \Sigma : B \subseteq A \}.$$ Even though this topology is highly non-Hausdorff, it's still pretty nice. For example, it's an Alexandroff space: arbitrary unions of closed sets are closed.

Being a topological space, $\Sigma$ now has a natural measurable structure, namely, the one generated by the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma^1 := \mathcal B_{\subseteq}(\Sigma)$.

- Is this space $(\Sigma, \Sigma^1)$ a reasonable one on which to do measure theory and probability?

Whether it is or not, there's some non-trivial structure present. For example, we can iterate this procedure. Set $\Sigma^0 = \Sigma$, and define $\Sigma^n := \mathcal B_{\subseteq}(\Sigma^{n-1}).$ Then each one of these spaces $\Sigma^n(X) := (\Sigma^{n}, \Sigma^{n+1})$ is measurable.

- Is $\Sigma : \mathrm{Meas} \to \mathrm{Meas}$ an endofunctor on the category of measurable spaces?
- Under what conditions does the sequence of measurable spaces $\Sigma^n(X)$ have a limit $\Sigma^{\infty}(X)$?

Comment: Tom, I don't think you mean what you said about Alexandroff spaces; arbitrary intersections of closed sets are always closed, in a topological space.

Comment: Thanks @Paul McKenney. It was a typo: Alexandroff spaces contain arbitrary unions of closed sets.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If $(X,\Sigma)$ is a measurable space, I think you are asking for a $\sigma$-algebra structure on $|\Sigma|$, the underlying set of $\Sigma$. We can identify this set with the set of measurable functions
$$|\Sigma|\cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Meas}}\;(X,2),$$
where $2$ is a two-point space with discrete $\sigma$-algebra.

Thus it suffices to prove a more general result: that $\text{Meas}$ is a [closed monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_monoidal_category). In other words, we would like to know that for any two measurable spaces, $X,Y$, there is a $\sigma$-algebra on the set of maps $\text{Hom}_{\text{Meas}}\;(X,Y)$, which has good formal properties (functoriality, right adjointness to $\otimes$).

The fact that $\text{Meas}$ is a symmetric monoidal closed category was proven by Kirk Sturtz in the paper [Categorical Probability Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.6030v4.pdf). See Section 2.3.

Comment: Let no one say category theory lacks practical applications. Thanks for the tip & the existence theorem, David! I will be very interested to hear more about the natural $\sigma$-algebra on the space of measurable functions Hom($X$, $Y$). Can you add some more details to your answer as to what that $\sigma$-algebra looks like? e.g., what are examples of measurable sets of maps, and do those form a base for the $\sigma$-algebra? What do functorality & right-adjointness mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this would be to ask the same question inside a suitable topos in which "everything is measurable" and such that each object is naturally equipped with the structure of a $\sigma$-algebra. In effect you would be expanding the notion of measure space to accommodate better structure, as such toposes typically contain the "classical" measure spaces.

For example, Matthew Jackson's Ph.D. dissertation "[A sheaf theoretic approach to measure theory"](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/students/jackson.pdf) might be a starting point.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer, that's an interest point of view. Can you expand more on it? Suppose we are considering the category $\operatorname{Meas}$, the topos-category $\operatorname{Set}$ and some other topos $\operatorname{T}$. What does it mean "to ask the same question" in that different topos? 

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\sdiff{\mathbin\triangle}$**Starting from literally just the measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$, I wouldn't think there's any particularly nice and natural $\sigma$-algebra on $\Sigma$; but with just a tiny bit more structure, there is! Namely:**

For any given equivalence class $\mathfrak{p}$ of probability measures on $(X,\Sigma)$ (where two probability measures being *equivalent* means that they agree on which sets have zero measure), we can define the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma_\mathfrak{p}^1$ on $\Sigma$ by
$$ \Sigma_\mathfrak{p}^1 \ = \ \sigma( \, \{ A \in \Sigma : \mathbb{P}(A \cap E) \leq r \} \, : \, E \in \Sigma, \, r \in [0,1] \, ), $$
i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra for which the map $A \mapsto \mathbb{P}(A \cap E)$ is measurable for each $E \in \Sigma$, where $\mathbb{P}$ may be any element of $\mathfrak{p}$. (This does not depend on the choice of $\mathbb{P}$, as I will justify shortly.)

This can equivalently be expressed as
$$ \Sigma_\mathfrak{p}^1 \ = \ \sigma( \, \{ A \in \Sigma : \mathbb{P}(A \sdiff E) \leq r \} \, : \, E \in \Sigma, \, r \in [0,1] \, ), $$
since
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A \sdiff E) &= \mathbb{P}(A \cap (X \setminus E)) + \mathbb{P}(E) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap E) \\
\mathbb{P}(A \cap E) &= \tfrac{1}{2}\!\bigl( \mathbb{P}(E) + 1 - \mathbb{P}(A \sdiff X) - \mathbb{P}(A \sdiff E) \bigr).
\end{align*}

---

A slightly cleaner way of thinking about essentially the same thing: Let $\tilde{\Sigma}_\mathfrak{p}$ be the quotient of $\Sigma$ under the equivalence relation
$$ A \sim B \ \Longleftrightarrow \ A \sdiff B \,\text{ is a $\mathfrak{p}$-null set.} $$
Given any $\mathbb{P} \in \mathfrak{p}$, we can define a metric $d_\mathbb{P}$ on $\tilde{\Sigma}_\mathfrak{p}$ by
$$ d_\mathbb{P}([A],[B]) = \mathbb{P}(A \sdiff B). $$
The topology induced by this metric is independent of the choice of $\mathbb{P}$. [Proof: given $A \in \Sigma$ and a sequence $(A_n)$ in $\Sigma$, if $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{P}'$ are probability measures with $\mathbb{P}(A_n \sdiff A) \to 0$ and $\mathbb{P}'(A_n \sdiff A) \not\to 0$, then we can find a subsequence $(A_{k_n})$ with $\inf_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}'(A_{k_n} \sdiff A) > 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(A_{k_n} \sdiff A) \leq \frac{1}{2^n}$, and so the set $\,\bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{m \geq n} (A_{k_m} \sdiff A)\,$ is $\mathbb{P}$-null but not $\mathbb{P}'$-null, and so $\mathbb{P}$ is not equivalent to $\mathbb{P}'$.]

This topology is quite nice; e.g. it is completely metrisable (with $d_\mathbb{P}$ being a complete metric), and if $\Sigma$ is countably generated then this topology is also separable (and hence Polish). The Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\smash{\tilde{\Sigma}}_\mathfrak{p}^1$ of this topology is precisely
$$ \smash{\tilde{\Sigma}}_\mathfrak{p}^1 \ = \ \sigma( \, \{ [A] \in \tilde{\Sigma}_\mathfrak{p} : \mathbb{P}(A \sdiff E) \leq r \} \, : \, E \in \Sigma, \, r \in [0,1] \, ). $$
Hence there is a trivial identification between $\smash{\tilde{\Sigma}}_\mathfrak{p}^1$ and $\Sigma_\mathfrak{p}^1$.

Comment: What about this uses probability-ness?